VBA Code Still Copies but No Longer Pastes to Another Workbook
After working for years, this code stops progress at the spot where it should Paste data.  The Paste option in ribbon is greyed out, so it has nothing to paste??  After several hours of effort, I just can't make it work again.  In case it helps, the whole workflow is that when the Print button is clicked for an invoice, an Export Table is populated with data and that data is coped and pasted to the Inventory Tracking file, then all open workbooks are saved and closed. If no solution, I will try devolving the workbook it pastes to until it works, figuring something there must be upsetting the paste process.
Sub CopyPasteToTracking()

    Sheets("Export Table").Select
    Range("$A$1:$K$" & Range("M1")).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheets("Sales Record").Range("AC6").Value
    ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=5
    Sheets("Sales").Activate
    Range("$A$1:$K$1").Paste
        
    For Each w In Application.Workbooks
        w.Save
        Next w
        Application.Quit
        
End Sub


Do yourself a major favor, and read How to avoid select in VBA?. You also don't have to ScrollWorkbookTabs - you can just paste to the desired sheet without scrolling to it.

Check that your destination workbook has not become readonly - that can also happen if someone else (or even yourself) has it open. Cells can be locked too ... there are reasons for not being able to paste, basically, that you need to check.

Thank you for your suggestions.  I got rid of Select and confirmed that the target workbook is not read only.  It still manages to go to correct paste, moving with dynamic range (not shown before), but stubbornly refuses to Paste.

Is there any event code in the target workbook?

If you have updated the code to no-longer-use-select/activate, it may help to update your question to reflect that so people can see if you missed something?

Yay! Finally got it worked out:
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheets("Sales Record").Range("AC6").Value

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
wb1.Sheets("Sales").Select
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Export Table").Activate
Range("$A$1:$K$" & (Range("M1"))).Select
Selection.Copy

wb1.Sheets("Sales").Activate
Range("$A$" & (Range("Y1"))).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
For Each w In Application.Workbooks
    w.Save
    Next w
    Application.Quit

